# What is the best idiom to convert a spliterator to a list in Java?

Tags: java, spliterator

I want to convert a `Spliterator<T>` into a `List<T>` in Java.

What is the best idiom to do that? I'm currently using the following code:

```
 List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
 spliterator.forEachRemaining(list::add);
```

Is there a simpler / faster way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
 StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false).collect(Collectors.toList())
```